# Marketing Cloud _Unsubscribe view returns a different count for status "Unsubscribed" than if I search manually in the All subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

If I run the following query in a Marketing Cloud (Corporate version account so there are no BUs):

SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey, Status
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE Status = 'Unsubscribed'

I get a count of 545,350

However, if I navigate to the All Subscribers list and search for status of "Unsubscribed", I get 560,035.

While this is live data and I might expect a difference of a few, why is there a ~15k difference? They should be the same. What is being pulled in by the search in the All Subscribers list that isn't being pulled in by the _Subscribers view and what should the query be to return the same count as pulling the count manually in the All Subscribers list?

Answer (score 0):

These data views do NOT surface the same information. _Subscribers shows the current status of the subscriber on the "All Subscriber" list, while the _unsubscribe dataview is unsubscribes from email sends (engagement data) A subscriber can exist multiple time on the _unsubscribe dataview.

Everything in the _unsubscribe dataview will have a jobid/listid associated with it